# Changing CSS by checking a checkbox - Redux Framework

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, redux-framework

I'm building a theme options system to my theme using the Redux framework.
I want to append a css property (background-image) when the user press specific button in a "Button Set" field.
The code:

```
array(
        'id'        => 'opt_change_menu_button',
        'type'      => 'button_set',
        'title'     => __('Change Menu Button', 'faster'),
        'options'   => array(
                        'yes' => __('Yes', 'faster'),
                        'no' => __('No', 'faster'),
                        ),
        'defualt'  => 'no',
),
```

When the user press YES, I want, in addition to what already happen (some other options appear in the bottom), to append a CSS property in the front end ( background-image: none), that overwrites the other properties which relate to the chosen selector.
In some other fields it is possible using the "output" value, but in that case I didn't fiend it possible, after hours of struggling.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev of Redux here. You'll have to append your own JavaScript for in-panel changes via JS. Luckily, it's quite easy. https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/custom-panel-css/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did change the JavaScript in my panel, but it doesn't work correctly. What I did is append CSS when some button is clicked on the panel using the ".css" jQuery function, but it takes effect only in the back-end, doesn't work on the front-end. Any solution for this?